# JQuery shortcut for sending ajax/JSON requests

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a application that uses a REST architecture style. Hence, I often do some calls to the backend with JSON data.

jQuery is new to me and up to now, the only syntax that worked for me is :

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/api/something/',
  type: 'POST',
  contentType:"application/json", //Or I will get 400 : Bad request
  data: JSON.stringify({key : "value"}),
  success: function (data) {
    console.log("data : %o", data);
  }
});
```

But I do not want to write explicitly `contentType:"application/json"` and  `JSON.stringify` at every call. I would prefer something like :

```
$.someFunction({
  url: '/api/something/',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {key : "value"},
  success: function (data) {
    console.log("data : %o", data);
  }
});
```

Maybe I could make a function in order to factorize this but I feel that jQuery should have a pre-existing function for that.

Anyone knows such function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try extending jQuery:

```
$.extend({doPost: function(url, data, success, error) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: success,
        error: error
    });
  }
});

$.doPost('/api/something/', {"key" : "value"}, function(data) {
    console.log("data : %o", data);
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that `new` is intended?

Comment: Why -1 on this solution? Is it a bad practice?

Comment: I didn't downvote but he likely meant to omit the `new` there.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong I'm not sure if "new" works here.. I'm searching

Comment: @Ragnar I am not expert in JS so I do not know if `new` is good here. But I tested and it works (very well, thanks!) without it.

Comment: You can remove "new", I've tested the code and it works without "new"

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap everything in a function and pass the parameters you need.

```
var thinPostWrapper = function(url, data, success) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: url
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: success
    });
}

thinPostWrapper('/api/something/', {"key" : "value"}, function(data) {
    console.log("data : %o", data);
});
```

Comment: It's preferable to `return $.ajax` so you can hook on it with deferreds/promises. As it's now it returns `undefined` which is pretty meaningless

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thanks for your comment, incorporated the change.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$.post(
   'api/something', 
   { key: 'value' }, 
   function( data ) {
     ...
   }, 
   'json'
);
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ for more details

Comment: Hmm, I get 415 (Unsupported Media Type).

Answer (score 0):

Try with [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: url,
 data: data,
 success: success,
 dataType: dataType
});
```